# Inside the function how to check if an edge exists, so that edge is not re-inserted in C

Tags: c

```
int addEdge(struct Graph* graph, int src, int dest) {

    struct AdjListNode *newNode = newListNode(dest);
    newNode->next = graph->array[src].head;
    graph->array[src].head = newNode;

    newNode = newListNode(src);
    newNode->next = graph->array[dest].head;
    graph->array[dest].head = newNode;

}
```

Comment: just look at nodes from *graph->array[src].head* to see if you have one for *dest*. WHat is your problem ?

Comment: The problem is that i don't know how to do it.

Comment: probably *addEdge* was not written by you then. Look how *addEdge* is implemented and you can deduce easily how to search if the edge already exists

Comment: No i didn't write this part of the function.

Answer (score 0):

That's how i did it!

```
int addEdge(struct Graph* graph, int src, int dest) {

    if (src == dest) {
        printf("Can't connect the same node");
        return 0;
    }
    node *nodeList2  = graph->array[src].head;
    while (nodeList2  != NULL) {
        if (nodeList2->dest == dest || nodeList2->dest == src) {
            printf(" the edge exists %d και %d", src, dest);
            return 0;
        }
          nodeList2  = nodeList2->next;
        }

        node *newNode = newListNode(dest);
        newNode->next = graph->array[src].head;
        graph->array[src].head = newNode;

        newNode = newListNode(src);
        newNode->next = graph->array[dest].head;
        graph->array[dest].head = newNode;
}
```